# unexpected extra copy of google doc in google drive root

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have an invoice template which is a google doc saved in GOOGLE DRIVE\SYSTEM\ named (invoice template.gdoc)
My goal is to make a copy of this template to GOOGLE DRIVE\SYSTEM\INVOICE PDF\INVOICE TEMP FOLDER, use "replaceText" to create individual invoice and save the created invoice as a pdf in the GOOGLE DRIVE\SYSTEM\INVOICE PDF. And the new pdf is downloadable with the http script so that user can immediately open and print.

My folder structure are as follow:

GOOGLE DRIVE\SYSTEM\INVOICE PDF\INVOICE TEMP FOLDER (ID: TEMPFOLDER, temp invoice google doc saved here and will be deleted immediately at the end of the function)

GOOGLE DRIVE\SYSTEM\INVOICE PDF\  (ID: PDF FOLDER, newly created pdf saved here)

GOOGLE DRIVE\SYSTEM\   (invoice template saved here)

GOOGLE DRIVE\ (Google drive root)

I achieved my goal. However, there is an unexpected copy of google doc in the GOOGLE DRIVE ROOT named (Copy of invoice template.gdoc) appears. Which part went wrong?

```
//function to create an invoice pdf
function createInvoiceAndPrint(grabConfirmEntryValue, entryNumber, invoiceNumber, invoiceTime) {


  const templateInvoice = DriveApp.getFileById("template file id");
  const invoiceTempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("TEMPFOLDER");
  const invoiceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("PDF FOLDER");
  const tempInvoiceTemplate = templateInvoice.makeCopy(invoiceTempFolder);
  const tempInvoiceDoc = DocumentApp.openById(tempInvoiceTemplate.getId());
  const body = tempInvoiceDoc.getBody();

  body.replaceText("{EntryNo.}", Utilities.formatString('%03d', invoiceNumber ));
  //and a bunch of rewrite content code here...

  tempInvoiceDoc.saveAndClose();
  const invoiceContentBlob = tempInvoiceTemplate.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  var newlyCreatedPdf = invoiceFolder.createFile(invoiceContentBlob).setName(invoiceNumber + ".pdf");

  var downloadLink = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput('<p>Entry ID: ' + entryNumber + '<br>Invoice No.: ' + invoiceNumber + '</p> <p>Print Invoice: <a href="' + newlyCreatedPdf.getUrl() + '" target="_blank">here</a>.</p>')
    .setWidth(300)
    .setHeight(200);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(downloadLink, "Sales Created");


  invoiceTempFolder.removeFile(tempInvoiceTemplate);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the reason for your issue of `However, there is an unexpected copy of google doc in the GOOGLE DRIVE ROOT named (Copy of invoice template.gdoc) appears.` is due to `invoiceTempFolder.removeFile(tempInvoiceTemplate);`. So, please modify it as follows.

#### From:

```
invoiceTempFolder.removeFile(tempInvoiceTemplate);
```

#### To:

```
// invoiceTempFolder.removeFile(tempInvoiceTemplate); // Remove this line.
```

- And also, `removeFolder(child)` has already been deprecated. Please be careful about this. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#removeFolder(Folder))

### Added:

From your following reply,

> I need only the pdf

If you want to remove the copied template document, please modify your showing script as follows.

#### From:

```
invoiceTempFolder.removeFile(tempInvoiceTemplate);
```

#### To:

```
tempInvoiceTemplate.setTrashed(true);
```

- By this, the copied template document is moved to the trash box.

Comment: do you mean only remove this line? Then how do I delete the temporary copy I made as a .gdoc? I need only the pdf, thank you! `// invoiceTempFolder.removeFile(tempInvoiceTemplate)`

Comment: @Gaspar Lam Thank you for replying. About `do you mean only remove this line?`, I apologize for my poor English skill. Please remove that line and test it again. `removeFile` has already been deprecated. But, unfortunately, even when that is used, no error occurs. `removeFile` removes the folder from the file. I thought that the reason for your issue of `However, there is an unexpected copy of google doc in the GOOGLE DRIVE ROOT named (Copy of invoice template.gdoc) appears. is due to invoiceTempFolder.removeFile(tempInvoiceTemplate);` is due to that. I apologize for my answer.

Comment: @Gaspar Lam About I need only the pdf, I added one more modification point in my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Yes. My work flow is, Invoice template.gdoc -->a copy of invoice template.gdoc with individual sales record--->save as pdf---> delete the copy of invoice template.gdoc with individual sales record

Comment: @Gaspar Lam Thank you for replying. From your reply, my added modification will achieve your goal. If I misunderstood your actual goal, I apologize.

Comment: @Gaspar Lam As another method for removing the file, when Drive API is used, I think that `Drive.Files.remove(tempInvoiceTemplate.getId())` can be used. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/delete) But, in this case, the file is completely deleted. So, if you use this, please be careful about this.

Comment: Awesome, this line of code works. No more copy of invoice template in the google drive root folder now. Thank you! `tempInvoiceTemplate.setTrashed(true)`